# How to pass data from client to server when using gSOAP?

Tags: c++, c, web-services, parsing, gsoap

I am trying to exchange data between client and server using gSOAP. Actually, I succeeded to send data from client to server but not from server to client. So, could someone please explain what functions to use to pass data from server to client?

Thanks for your time and replies,

Comment: Not clear what you mean sending data from server to client.  Do your calls to the server complete?  If you follow the gSOAP howto what errors do you get?  Or are you actually trying to have the server invoke the conversation; i.e. without the client making a request?

Comment: I am trying to invoke a conversation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know is by invoking with a function soap_call
See the example of calc in gsoap package

Comment: Thanks! this is valid form client, but form the sever is not. Is there anyting else